# Undefined columns selected in sidebarpanel in Rshiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am quite new in Shiny, so forgive me for asking a so basic question.

I am trying to develop a basic data analysis app, in order to deal with big databases. I have already been able of importing the DDBB and to visualize it as a table. However, when trying to perform a summary statistics about the variables, I have the error of: "Undefinded columns selected" and I cannot see anything. If I do not add any code in the server, I can see the output (boxplot, histogram and summary) in the app, but I cannot see variable names (only 1,2,3...). I show my code below.

I will really appreciate any help to solve this issue. Thank you very much.

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

    main_page <- tabPanel(
        title = "Statistics",
        titlePanel("Statistical Analysis"),
        
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
                # Añado el archivo que quiero cargar
                fileInput('DDBB', 'Choose file to upload',
                          accept = c(
                              'text/csv',
                              'text/comma-separated-values',
                              '.csv'
                          )),
                #checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
                #tags$hr(),
                selectInput('Variable', 'Select a variable', "",
                            choice=c((1:33)), multiple = FALSE,
                            selectize = TRUE
                            ),
                  sliderInput("bins",
                              "Number of bins:",
                              min = 1,
                              max = 200,
                              value = 30)
            ),
            
            mainPanel(
                tabsetPanel(
                    tabPanel(
                        title = "Data Visualization",
                       
                        DT::dataTableOutput("sample_table")
                    ),
                    tabPanel(
                        title = "Summary Statistics",
                        verbatimTextOutput("sum"),
                        fluidRow(splitLayout(cellWidths = c("50%", "50%"),
                                             plotOutput("box"),
                                             plotOutput('hist'))
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )

  
))
```

```
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

# Output a file input (cargar archivo).
    df_products_upload <- reactive({ 
        inFile <- input$DDBB 
        print(inFile)
        if (is.null(inFile))
            return(NULL)
        df <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE,sep = ';')
       # updateSelectInput(session, "Variable", choices = names(df))
        return(df)
    })

  
    output$sample_table<- DT::renderDataTable({ 
        df <- df_products_upload() 
        DT::datatable(df,
                      filter = 'top') %>%
            formatRound(columns= c(1:ncol(df)), digits = 2)
    })
    
    
    observeEvent(df_products_upload(), {
      updateSelectInput(session, "Variable", choices = colnames(df_products_upload()))
    })
    
    output$sum <- renderPrint({
      updateSelectInput(session, "Variable", choices = colnames(df)
        summary(df[,as.numeric(input$Variable)])
    })
    
    output$box <- renderPlot({
      updateSelectInput(session, "Variable", choices = colnames(df_products_upload))
        x<-summary(df[,as.numeric(input$Variable)])
        boxplot(x,col="sky blue",border="purple",main=names(df[as.numeric(input$Variable)]))

    })
    
    output$hist <- renderPlot({
      updateSelectInput(session, "Variable", choices = colnames(df_products_upload))
        # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
        x<-df[,as.numeric(input$Variable)]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
        # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
        hist(x, 
             main=names(df[as.numeric(input$Variable)]) ,
             breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'black',
             xlab = 'samples')
        
    })
    
  
    
   
 
})
```

Comment: Without details of your data file, we cannot help you.

Comment: I have a ddbb in which samples are in rows and variables in columns. All the columns are numeric (metabolite determinations) except for the firest one which is a character. My DDBB is a csv file and it does not have missing values.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack-Overflow, Enrique :) I added a line to save iris dataset as ';'-separated csv and used that as uploadable data example. I must say, your code had multiple errors, both shiny and also a bit basic base R data.frame manipulation. I have corrected them and added comments. All beginnings are hard. I would suggest you to go back and do some more shiny exercises and tutorials. I think you will advance faster that way.

Especially revisit reactive expressions:
https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson6/
It matters if you pass as parameter the value of a reactive `sum(my_reactive_numbers())` or the reactive it self `sum(my_reactive_numbers)`.

Also check out scope rules for shiny reactive contexts. Basically like functions, what is defined within one reactive context, is not automatically exposed to others, hence the df issues. If you would want to (probably not) make a variable global, here is a deeper intro into that:
https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html

```
library(DT)

write.table(iris,file = "./sample_upload_data_set.csv",sep = ";") #; because assmed in code

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  main_page <- tabPanel(
    title = "Statistics",
    titlePanel("Statistical Analysis"),
    
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        # Añado el archivo que quiero cargar
        fileInput('DDBB', 'Choose file to upload',
                  accept = c(
                    'text/csv',
                    'text/comma-separated-values',
                    '.csv'
                  )),
        #checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
        #tags$hr(),
        selectInput('Variable', 'Select a variable', NULL,
                    choices = NULL,    #edits start with NULL as no data set yet
                    multiple = FALSE,
                    selectize = TRUE
        ),
        sliderInput("bins",
                    "Number of bins:",
                    min = 1,
                    max = 200,
                    value = 30)
      ),
      
      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel(
            title = "Data Visualization",
            
            DT::dataTableOutput("sample_table")
          ),
          tabPanel(
            title = "Summary Statistics",
            verbatimTextOutput("sum"),
            fluidRow(splitLayout(cellWidths = c("50%", "50%"),
                                 plotOutput("box"),
                                 plotOutput('hist'))
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
  
  
))


# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  #expose an uplaoded csv file as a reactive data.frame
  df_products_upload <- reactive({  #todo consider a shorter name e.g. r_prod_up.df
    inFile <- input$DDBB  #
    print(inFile)
    #if (!is.null(inFile))
    #  return(NULL) do not use return in any shiny reactive context, it is not a function
    
    #req is practical replacement of if '(is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)'-pattern
    req(inFile$datapath) #must be not null, non_empty character, or reactive will not complete
    
    df <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE,sep = ';')
    # updateSelectInput(session, "Variable", choices = names(df))

    #return(df) ## EDIT do not use return
    df
  })
  
  #let data.frame column names be choices of an input 
  observe({ #edit observeEvent was redundant, just use observe here
    df <- df_products_upload()
    
    #the following code expects numeric columns
    the_numeric_columns <- colnames(df)[sapply(df,is.numeric)]
    
    updateSelectInput(session, "Variable", choices = the_numeric_columns)
  })
  
  
  


  #render the data.frme with data.table
  output$sample_table <- DT::renderDataTable({ 
    df <- df_products_upload() 
    DT::datatable(df, filter = 'top') %>%
      #formatRound will mask non numeric columns
      formatRound(
        columns = which(sapply(df,is.numeric)), #only format numeric columns
        digits = 2
      )
  })
  
  
  
  # but this render makes absolutely no sense, you should 
  output$sum <- renderPrint({
    
    #edit it is bad behavior to do side effects in render scopes
    # updateSelectInput(session, "Variable", choices = colnames(df_products_upload()) #edit df was not assign in scope
    #                   summary(df[,as.numeric(input$Variable)])
    # })
    
  }) # edit missing bracket
    
  output$box <- renderPlot({
    #browser()
    
    #edit bad behaviour, maybe you missunderstood the update functionSelectInput
    #updateSelectInput(session, "Variable", choices = colnames(df_products_upload())) #edit reactive must be read not passed directly to colnames
    
    #edit df is not assigened in this scope
    df <- df_products_upload()
    
    #x<-summary(df[,as.numeric(input$Variable)]) #edit this is no bueno, what if varaible names were ... names
    # edit since plucking only one column and dropping data.frame wrap
    # you may just use [[]] brackets to make it more explicit to the reader
    x<-df[[input$Variable]] #this can only return the vector of one column or NULL
    x<-summary(x) 
    
    
    boxplot(
      x,
      col="sky blue",
      border="purple",
      
      #comma was missing here, and why not just use Varaible 
      main = input$Variable
    
    )
    
  })
    
  output$hist <- renderPlot({
    #browser()
    #edit df is not assigened in this scope
    df <- df_products_upload()
    
    #update makes no sense here
    #updateSelectInput(session, "Variable", choices = colnames(df)) #edit if introducing df anyways just use that
    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    
    # edit since plucking only one column and dropping data.frame wrap
    # you may just use [[]] brackets to make it more explicit to the reader
    x<-df[[input$Variable]] #this can only return the vector of one column or NULL
    
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, 
         #main=names(df[as.numeric(input$Variable)]) , # you're assuming columns would be named by numbers...
         #...and it is quite like crossing the river to get water,
         main = input$Varible, 
         breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'black',
         xlab = 'samples'
    )
    
    
  })
    
    
    
    
    
}


shiny::shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate your help. You solved many doubts I had.